# Problem with css selectors and jQuery combination

Tags: css

I need this kind of div

```
<div id="out">
    <table id="tab">
        <tr><th>A</th></tr>
        <tr><td>B</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and at a certain point I need to execute this instruction:

```
$("#out > #tab > tr > td").css( "background-color", "rgb(0, 255, 0)");
```

because I need all the td to have a green background.
If instead of `#out>td` I use either `#out` or `td` it works fine, but not like this. Can you tell me why?
jQuery library is already included.

```js
$("#out > #tab > tr > td").css("background-color", "rgb(0, 255, 0)");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="out">
  <table id="tab">
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `$("#out > td")`  `>` in a css selector specifies a direct descendent.  td is not a direct descendent here.  Remove it and it will find the td.

Comment: Youe need a selector like this `#out > #tab > tr > td`

Comment: Just so it is clear, this is not a jQuery issue.  This same selector (#out > td) in a css rule would not do what you are expecting.  This is purely a selector issue.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Edit the question and show us what you tried?

Comment: the table cell is not a direct descendant. Make your selector less specific: `$("#out  td").css( "background-color", "rgb(0, 255, 0)");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fully qualified selector is not working because you left out the tbody tag that the browser will create.  I've provided two examples.  One using the fully qualified version, and another using the indirect selector.

```js
$("#out > #tab > tbody > tr > th").css("background-color", "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
$("#out td").css("background-color", "rgb(0, 255, 0)");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="out">
  <table id="tab">
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```